# Missing $ inserted, but a PDF is generated

Tags: errors

I have a problem which seems to be very common, but I cannot understand why LaTeX is complaining about a missing $ in this code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
{\LaTeX} supports matricies insertion through the \emph{amsmath} package. 

We can have \emph{plain} matricies:
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    a & b & c
\end{matrix}

We can have \emph{rounded} matricies:
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    a & b & c
\end{pmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Compilation results (pdflatex):

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.10 \begin{matrix}
```

The most strange thing is that, although the compilation fails, a PDF file is generated and it corresponds to the code I've written.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can only use `\begin{patrix}` and similar commands in math mode. surround with `$..$` or for display math `\[...\]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot, I'm still learning LaTeX and I did not know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `\begin{pmatrix}` and similar commands in math mode. Surround with `$..$` or for display math `\[...\]`

You would have two errors for each matrix. At the start TeX complains it is not in math mode so inserts a `$` so then processes the matrix in math mode, but does not know where to stop. You were lucky and had no text after the matrix so it stopped at the blank line and gave another error that `\par` is not allowed in math mode, so it inserted another `$` to get out of math mode.

By absolute chance that corresponded with the output you intended, but never use a PDF generated after an error, usually it is nonsense, just possibly useful for debugging.